# Standard Deviation over Datetime column grouped by Processname

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics

I have a Table with fields `ProcessName`, `StartDate` and `EndDate`. I need to know the standard deviation of the `EndDate` in order to know the limit of time I can wait for a process to finish. Based on this standard deviation e-mails will be sent if some process is taking too much time to run.

My idea was to use the following query:

```
select
    ProcessName,
    STDEV(tm)
from (
    select
        ProcessName,
        cast(EndDate as decimal(18,6)) tm
    from Reports..ExecutionControl
) t1
group by ProcessName
```

But, first I don't know what it returns (if it is percentage or not), and maybe this is a lack of statistical understanding, and also I need to get the time limit a process can take, and it is not calculating it.

Could someone help me to sort this out? Thanks in advance to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I'm not sure how you would use the standard deviation without an average, but that is your question.

I would expect a query like this:

```
select ProcessName,
       STDEV(dateadiff(second, Startdate, Enddate)) as stdev_dur
from Reports..ExecutionControl
group by ProcessName;
```

That is, the standard deviation is calculated based on the duration, not `EndDate`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I think at the end I will have to add this standard deviation in seconds to my `MAX(EndDate)`, right?

Comment: @LucasRezende . . . If you want the maximum plus one standard deviation, that is what you would do.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I needed to make some adjustments over the logic but the `STDEV` was it. :)